# Loading google search results(Mobile Version) in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I can load google search results in a webview by making a request to the url `http://www.google.com/search?q=searchterm` and loading the result on the webview using

```
wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, responseString,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

But this loads the PC-browser version of search results..I want the mobile version...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the user agent:

```
wb.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
```